# How to scan a list for a partial appearance using a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I’m trying to use a dictionary to scan a list of strings to see if it appears at all within the string for example let’s say I have a dictionary of {‘C99’:1, 'C4':1} with a list of [‘C99C2C3C5’, ‘C88C4’] then the new list would be [‘1’,'1’] because ‘C99’ appears within the string ‘C99C2C3C4’ and 'C4' appears in 'C88C4'.

My current method of doing this is:

```
import re

dict = {'C99': 1,'C15':1}
ComponentList = ['C1C15C99', 'C15', 'C17']

def func(s):
    for k, v in dict.items():
        if all(i in s for i in re.findall('\w\d', k)):
            return v
    else:
        return 0

ComponentList = [func(i) for i in ComponentList]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

Wanted Output:

```
[1,1,0]
```

For clarification, if this is my system:

```
my_dict = {'C1C55C99': 1, 'C17': 1, 'C3': 1}
component_list = ['C1C15C55C99', 'C15', 'C17']
```

Because 'C1C55C99' appears within 'C1C15C55C99' I'd want the value to change to the dictionary value to give an output:

```
results = ['1','0','1']
```

However, this method doesn’t work when the component number gets above C9 and am hoping someone could help me on a fix, so it can work for Cx and explain why the previous method didn’t work.

Thanks Ben

Comment: Is your dictionary actually called `dict`? That's a Python build-in so I'd caution against using that as a variable name.

Comment: Also I see no real purpose of using regex here with your code. Can't you just check `if k in s:` ?

Comment: This question is ambiguous. What should be the output if `dict = ['A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3]` and your list is `['A', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'ABC', 'ABCD']`?

Comment: Hi, the problem with using if 'k in s:' is if {'C1':1} is in my dictionary then if the list contains ['C19'] it will still change that C19 to 1 because C1 (From the dictionary) appears within ['C19']. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: The dictionary value will always be 1 so if I had a dict = ['A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1] the prevailing list would be [0,0,0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments here, it seems to me that the character `'C'` in your component list is significant because you seem to want to differentiate between `'C11'` for example and `'C1'`.

BTW, I fully agree with @martineau to always use standard naming in python. `CamleCasingLikeThis` should only be reserved for class names, and you should use `lower_case_like_this` for variables in general, and not capitalized.

Let's walk through how this can be done.

```
my_dict = {'C99': 1, 'C15': 1, 'C1': 1}
component_list = ['C1C15C99', 'C15', 'C17']

result = []

# first convert my_dict to a list of numbers ['99', '15', '1']
elements = [element[1:] for element in my_dict.keys()]

# for every component you want to characterize
for component in component_list:

    # a flag to know if we found any element in this component
    found = False

    # split the string by the 'C' character to get its sub element numbers
    # for example 'C1C15C99'.split('C') == ['', '1', '15', '99']
    for sub_elem in component.split('C'):

        # make sure sub_elem is not an empty string
        if sub_elem:

            # check if this sub element exists in elements
            if sub_elem in elements:

                found = True

                # exit the inner loop
                break

    # convert the boolean to int (either 0 or 1)
    # and finally add this to the result
    result.append(int(found))

print(result)
# [1, 1, 0]
```

---

So far, I've been under the presumption that `my_dict` can only take singular components like C1 or C6 but not composites like C12C14. From your latest [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963906/how-to-scan-a-list-for-a-partial-appearance-using-a-dictionary/54965418#comment96699044_54965418), it appears this is not the case. Two more things are suddenly made clear: `my_dict` can contain a combination of components, and when checking for existence of one in another, order doesn't matter. For example, C1C2 **does** exist in C5C2C7C1 but C1C2 **does not** exist in C1 since both sub components have to present.

This is very important and it changes the problem entirely. For future reference, please make sure to exhaustively describe your problem from t he start.

```
my_dict = {'C99': 1, 'C15': 1, 'C1': 1, 'C1C55C99': 1, 'C99C6': 1, 'C2C4C18': 1}
component_list = ['C1C15C99', 'C15', 'C17', 'C8C6C80C99', 'C6', 'C55C2C4C18C7', 'C55C1', 'C18C4']

result = []

# first convert my_dict to a list of lists containing singular elements
elements = [element.split('C')[1:] for element in my_dict.keys()]
# elements = [['2', '4', '18'], ['99'], ['1'], ['15'], ['99', '6'], ['1', '55', '99']]

for component in component_list:

    found = False

    # gather the sub elements for this components
    comp_elements = component.split('C')[1:]

    for composite_element in elements:

        element_exists = True

        # check if every singular element in this element is present in component
        for signular_element in composite_element:

            if signular_element not in comp_elements:
                element_exists = False
                break

        if element_exists:
            found = True
            break

    result.append(int(found))

print(result)
# [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Hi Darksky, I've now changed the variable names thanks for the heads up. With this code lets say I have a dictionary and list of my_dict = {'C1C55C99': 1, 'C17': 1, 'C3': 1}, component_list = ['C1C15C55C99', 'C15', 'C17'] because 'C1C5C99', from the dictionary, does appear in 'C1C15C55C99' it should change to the dictionary value 1 but doesn't. Hope you can help. Ben

Comment: I will be sure to add a more comprehensive description if I have any future questions as to not waste anyone's time. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm bad at one liners but it is much more simple than yours, and there was no need to use regex, just use `if x in y`

```
def func(s):
for k, v in dict.items():
    if k in s:
        return v
return 0
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with this is if {'C1':1} is in my dictionary then if the list contains ['C19'] it will still change that C19 to 1 because C1 appears within ['C19']. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Oh, so maybe you should use regex to split components that have multiple letters in them and then check with `==` or `is` instead of `in`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edits to your question and comments, I think I (finally) understand what it is you want to do, so here's my substantially revised answer.

I think the code shown could stand a little improvement/optimization, but would first like confirmation that it's now doing the right thing.

```
import re

def func(comps):
    pats = [c for c in re.findall(r'\w\d+', comps)]

    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if any(p in k for p in pats):
            return v

    return 0

# Testcases

my_dict = {'C99': 1, 'C4': 1}
components_list =  ['C99C2C3C5', 'C88C4']
result = [func(comps) for comps in components_list]
print('result:', result)  # -> result: [1, 1]

my_dict = {'C99': 1,'C15': 1}
components_list = ['C1C15C99', 'C15', 'C17']
result = [func(comps) for comps in components_list]
print('result:', result)  # -> result: [1, 1, 0]

my_dict = {'C1C55C99': 1, 'C17': 1, 'C3': 1}
components_list = ['C1C15C55C99', 'C15', 'C17']
result = [func(comps) for comps in components_list]
print('result:', result)  # -> result: [1, 0, 1]
```

**Note**: You really shouldn't name variables the same as Python built-ins, like `dict`, as it's confusing and can cause subtle bugs unless you're very careful (or just got lucky).

Generally I would suggest following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), especially the [Nnaming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) section, which would require also changing `ComponentList` into lowercase words separated by `"_"` characters—in this case, `components_list` would conform to the guidelines.

Comment: Hi Martineau,  With this code lets say I have a dictionary and list of my_dict = {'C1C55C99': 1, 'C17': 1, 'C3': 1}, component_list = ['C1C15C55C99', 'C15', 'C17'] because 'C1C5C99', from the dictionary, does appear in 'C1C15C55C99' it should change to the dictionary value 1 but doesn't. Hope you can help. Ben